# NodeMCU ESP32 as a replacement for my arduino project

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, esp32, nodemcu

I would just like to ask if this microcontroller can power or can manage 2 servos, 2 motors, and 2 hc-sr04 ultrasonic distance sensor combined? Also, does this board come with a bluetooth module?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StarCat but how would I do the "logic level translation"?

Comment: Easiest would be to use the little 4-channel bidirectional level converters. Sometimes a simple voltage divider made out of two resistors would be enough (5V output to 3.3V input) and some 5V peripherals are 3.3V tolerant.

Comment: thank you so much @StarCat

Answer (score 4):

The ESP32 has more than enough free GPIOs to manage those peripherals. Also, the ESP32 does indeed come with a bluetooth module.

Your question about powering these peripherals very much depends on their power requirements. I would not count on being able to run motors or servos from the internal power supply of a NodeMCU board, so you would need an external supply.

Also, note that the ESP32 is a 3.3V device and might require logic level translation if you’re using 5V peripherals.